# Event listener can't read correct return from another function

Tags: javascript, events

I have some code where I have set up an event listener. The event listener looks something like this:

```
api.setListener(function(message) {
    myFunction(message);
});
```

*This is obviously not the actual code, but it's the same idea.*

This event listener will be called/run every single time the `api` receives a message from the server. Upon receiving a message, the `api` will call `myFunction` and pass in message to it.

The `myFunction` looks like this:

```
function myFunction(message) {
    var otherStuff = getOtherStuff(message.name);

    if(otherStuff.isGood) {
        ...
    }
}
```

The `checkGoodness` function is a function that, based on the message name passed in to it, will search through an object and will return the key of that object with the same `.name` property.

The `getOtherStuff` function looks like this:

```
function getOtherStuff(name) {
    for(var thing in obj) {
        if(obj.hasOwnProperty(thing)) {
            if(obj[thing].name === name) {
                return obj[thing];
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Now here is where the problem comes in: even though the name may exist in a property of `obj`, this function will *always* return `null`.

But this is very confusing. I have set up many `console.log`s to log...

- `obj`.
- `obj[thing]`.
- `name`, to make sure it was passed in correctly.
- "good" if the conditional passed and `return obj[thing]` is about to run.
- "bad" if it did not pass and `return null` is about to run.

And everything seems as expected: `obj` and it's properties are correct, `name` is passed in correctly, `"good"` is printed, `"bad"` is not: everything seems all perfect.

However, when I insert a `console.log` into `myFunction` to check the return of `getOtherStuff`, I get `null`.

What is causing this? Why? Is it something to do with the event like I predict?

---

In the case that my pseudo-code is not entirely accurate, here is the actual code:

```
function findZone(id) {
    var zoneGroups = [playerInfos.user.zones, playerInfos.opponent.zones];

    for(var i = 0, length = zoneGroups.length; i < length; i++) {
        for(var zone in zoneGroups[i]) {
            if(zoneGroups[i].hasOwnProperty(zone)) {
                console.log(zoneGroups[i][zone].id, id, zoneGroups[i][zone].id === id);
                if(zoneGroups[i][zone].id === id) {
                    return zoneGroups[i][zone];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried putting a console.log after the return statement and after printing "good"?

Comment: @sunny Yes. I have tried placing `console.log`s before and after both return statements. Out of the 4 `console.log`s around the return statements, only one ran: the one before `return obj[thing]`

Comment: Are any of your operations asynchronous such as `getOtherStuff()`.  A common mistake with async stuff is to not properly wait for the completion of the async operation before trying to use the results.

Comment: have you tried printing obj[thing] just before returning? if so, what does that yield?

Comment: @jfriend00 `getOtherStuff` is not async.

Comment: @sunny That yields the correct value.

Comment: Try using `console.log(obj[thing].name, name, obj[thing].name === name)` inside the loop, and check if there is some match.

Comment: @Oriol The first two yield the correct name and the last one yields true; all the values are correct.

Comment: @SirPython No idea, that shouldn't be possible :S

Comment: @Oriol That's what I keep on saying, but it's obviously possible.

Comment: @Oriol Do you think it would help if I posted the actual code, instead of a pseudo example, in case I'm not providing enough information?

Comment: @SirPython Yes, maybe the pseudo example lacks something that explains this behavior with the real code.

Comment: Sorry, I can't understand how this can happen.

Comment: Please also add a `console.log` before the `return null` statement. Then please post the complete log you're getting in the question. My guess is that the listener is called multiple times, and you didn't distinguish the different calls to `findZone`.

Comment: @Bergi Please read the comments. I *did* put a `console.log` before the `return null` statement; it is not run. And yes, you are correct in saying that the listener is called multiple times, but what you mean that I possibly "didn't distinguish the different calls to `findZone`"?

Comment: @Oriol Would you help if I linked you to the file in the main repo?

Comment: @SirPython: Ah, right, sorry. I meant that possibly you would debug the "good" call, and then found `null` in  the following "bad" call, but you seem to have checked that. So your problem is that `otherStuff` is `null`? That should indeed not be possible, unless `.id` is a getter with the side effect of nulling the zone. A link to the whole code so that we can try to reproduce this might be helpful, yes.

Comment: @SirPython Now I'm going to sleep, but the link might help someone else.

Comment: @Bergi Here is the [link](https://github.com/Cardshifter/HTML-Client/blob/game-board/src/game_board/controller.js). I apologize for being late: I did not get the notification. If you want, we can communicate further in chat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code was actually half working and half not.

There were in fact 10 messages being sent. The first 5 would fail because of other, server related issues, and the second 5 would succeed. I don't know why my `console.log`s didn't reveal that before.

The fix was a simple `try/catch`.